# Getting blogs from mysite

Tags: blog, mysite

I want to retrieve blogs from mysite but I don't know how to do it. I have this code which gives me url of mysite but how to retrieve blogs?

```
var profileManager = new UserProfileManager(SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Site));
        var profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName);
        using (SPSite personalSite = profile.PersonalSite)
        {
            lblUrl.Text = personalSite.Url;
            //lblBlog.Text = ??????????
        }
```